# Finding the first item amongst a series of items in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data in C# and I need to find the occurrence of the first `BUY` / `SELL` (See `Status` column) along with the corresponding `Stock` and its corresponding `Price`.

For example I have the following items in my list ordered according to `Date`:

[image]

I have highlighted the occurrence of the first `BUY` and `SELL` in yellow for `AAPL` and in orange for `MSFT` for a better understanding.

The LINQ query should give me the following result:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share the code you've got so far?

Comment: I tried using a if loop : if (ListData[i].Status.CompareTo(Status) != 0), but this method doesnt work under certain conditions. I havent used Linq because i am a novice in Linq

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Why is the record from 8/21 included? Why is 8/25 included?

Comment: Yeah what is the correlation of buy AAPL and selling MSFT seems like they should have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @JohnWu if I’m understanding correctly, it’s the first occurrence where the action changes from buy to sell or vice versa

Comment: @SamMarion there is no correlation between the different stocks, i believe he wants to apply the same filtering to any stock.

Comment: @JohnWu: On 8/21, BUY occurred after a series of SELL's. Thus it is the first occurance of a BUY on 8/21, and hence it is shown in the result screenshot. Similar Logic for 8/25

Comment: @SamMarion:Ture, there is no correlation of the Stock column here.

Comment: @JohnWu : You are right - it’s the first occurrence where the action changes from buy to sell or vice versa"

Comment: @InBetween: Yes it can be done, but i wanted to understand if it can done done using LINQ

Answer (score 3):

You can use the overload of `Where` that supplies the index, and compare to the prior record like this:

```
var results = data.Where( (r, i) => i == 0 || data[i-1].Status != r.Status);
```

The above assumes a `List<T>`. If all you have is an `IEnumerable` it's a little more messy but you can use:

```
    var results2 = data.Where( r =>
        {
            var prior = data.Where(j => j.Date < r.Date)
                            .OrderByDescending(j => j.Date)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
            return (prior == null || prior.Status != r.Status);
        }
    );
```

Or, of course, you can just create a list and use that:

```
var list = data.ToList();
var results = list.Where( (r, i) => i == 0 || list[i-1].Status != r.Status);
```

[Full example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ccFis).

Comment: That's the code (I mean Record class and filling list with those records) OP should have attached to the question! A bit pity this code won't work with IEnumerable (because of `data[i-1]`).

Comment: Thank you for all the effort. I will try this out :)

Comment: Good point about `IEnumerable`; I edited my answer with a second solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Transaction
    {
         public DateTime Date {get; set;}
         public string Stock {get; set;}
         public decimal Price {get; set;}
    }
```

If I understand correctly you have a list of objects? If what you want is to get a list of Buy, Sell, Buy, Sell... ordered by date your only option seems to be a loop.

```
var status = "BUY";
List<Transaction> newList = new List<Transaction>();
    foreach (var item in list.OrderBy(x=>x.Date)){
     if(item.Status == status){
          newList.Add(item);
          status = status == "BUY"?"SELL":"BUY";
     }
}
```

"list" is the original list of objects. "newList" is what is returned from the loop.

Comment: "you want is to get a list of Buy, Sell, Buy, Sell"- True. But I also need the corresponding Date, Stock, Price in the list

Comment: The new list will return a list of objects. Check out the edit. The loop is adding the object to a new list when the status matches. Once you're done looping it returns a list.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps :-)